# Exclude file in npm scripts

Tags: javascript, terminal, npm

I've been hunting around on stackoverflow but I can't find a method to exclude a file from being included in the linter script I have. I am trying to exclude the `karma.conf.js` file:

`"lint": "node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js --ext=.js client/ lib/ models/ routes/ test/backend/ *.js !karma.conf.js"`

I've tried using: `-I`, `--exclude='karma.conf.js'`, `--ignore=karma.conf.js` and a few others, but no luck. Any advice?

Comment: Did you try [reading the documentation?](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#ignoring-files-and-directories)

Comment: @MikeC I was reading the npm scripts documentation, but this would make more sense. Thanks.